# Entity Framework table-per-type advice needed

Tags: inheritance, entity-framework-4, table-per-type

I need to implement solution with 1 base class and 3 sub-classes (**4 classes**)
**Base class:** *User*
**Sub-classes:** *Client*, *OfficeUser*, *Employee*

In my database I have **only 3 tables** : *Users*, *Clients* and *Employees*. 
I don't have *OfficeUsers* table since all data that I need is already in *Users* table.
 
In the future I want to be able to create report lisitng number of Clients, Employees and OfficeUsers.

I don't want to use TPH since I have lots of non-nullable fields in Clients and Employees table.
Should I create *OfficeUsers* table with only UserId so I can implement TPT? 
It looks for me as not very good design - having table with only PK so I can map it properly - please correct me if this is the way to do it.

Another option was to have *UserType* colum within *Users* table and use it as discriminator but will it work with TPT? Is it possible to create TPT with 1 missing table and use discriminators, looks like mixing TPT and TPH which I think is not possible.

Thanks in advance for your answers.

**EDIT:**

Please also consider this scenario:
I'm introducing new class called `MobileUser` which also has the same fields as `User`. In that case I have no way of knowing how many `MobileUsers` and how many `OfficeUsers` is the system without introducing new column for user type. 
Is having in this scenario 2 empty tables (only PK) is better/worse than creating dependency in my queries on number of tables and additionally preventing me from using some LINQ queries (please see my comments under Ladislav Mrnka answer )

**EDIT 2:**

There is a chance that I'll have to add fields to `OfficeUser` in the future so I'm starting to think that empty table can somehow be an option, at least C# code (queries) would look cleaner. Let me know if you have better approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is just a problem of perspective, rather than an architectural one... because whatever you do, you end up with a single PK table.

You can make an *OfficeUsers* table, which can contain just the PK of the *User*... just don't make it an inherited type. Now you have a list of all users who use the office, which you can query against. The structure is exactly the same, but the thinking is a bit different.

If you had multiple offices, you'd have a table of offices with an id, then your *OfficeUser* would have it's own type table, as the extra field would be the office foreign key... giving you the distinction you wanted.

But, as you only (I presume) have one office, you don't need a foreign key, so you just need one table to hold the users who use the office... it's "6 of one, half a dozen of the other", exactly the same really, whichever way you choose.

This is why I'd go with your instinct in your 2nd edit, you might add more fields later, so you may as well make an "empty" type... because either way, you'll end up with a table that just stores PKs.

Answer (score 0):

If your `OfficeUser` is exactly same like `User` then you don't need any additional class. Use `User` instead of `OfficeUser` and derived classes for `Employee` and `Client`

Comment: @ladislav-mrnka I was thinking about that but then I won't be able to use queries like `where user is OfficeUser` or `from ou in entities.Users.OfType<OfficeUser>()`. To find out number of OfficeUsers I will have to get all users where user is NOT Client or Employee

Comment: Yes that is true. You will have to use `Where(x => !(x is Employee))`

Comment: @ladislav-mrnka Yup, and when I introduce new table such as `MobileUser` I'll have to modify queries to make sure it includes another table (in this case 3 "is not" statements in where clause). Do you think this solution is better than creating empty table for *OfficeUser* ?

Comment: No it is not better solution but adding empty table doesn't seem like solution as well. I will think about that.